# Counting and grouping records up to a certain value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table on my MS SQL2008R2 server containing historical telephone call data, which contains a record ID, a Timestamp, and a boolean indicator of whether the call was connected or not.

I'd like to determine how many calls were made for each record up to and including the first "connected record". For example, for record ID `ABC123`

- 5 calls were made to a record
- the first two didn't connect
- The third and fourth calls did connect
- The fifth one didn't connect

.. the output would be

```
  RecordID    CallsUntilSuccessful
  ABC123           3
```

I know I could do a simple `COUNT`/`GROUP BY` if I was just looking for the number of calls per record. I can't figure out, however, to only count calls up to and including the first row where `Connected` is `true`.

So far I have:

```
select RecordID, Timestamp, Connected,
row_number() over ( partition by RecordID order by Timestamp asc)
from historyTable
```

which gives me each call attempt: the call detail (ID, timestamp etc) and the which number attempt it was. Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: it's surprising that you just need such a simple result, so there is a simpler query like in this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1ed3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a sub-query which counts the number of rows until the call was successful:

```
SELECT h1.RecordID, 
       h1.Timestamp, 
       h1.Connected,
       CallsUntilSuccessful = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
                              (
                                SELECT 1 FROM HistoryTable h2
                                WHERE h1.RecordID = h2.RecordID
                                  AND h2.Connected = 1
                              ) THEN NULL 
                              ELSE
                              ( 
                                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                FROM HistoryTable h2
                                WHERE h1.RecordID = h2.RecordID
                                  AND h2.Connected = 0
                                  AND NOT EXISTS 
                                 (
                                    SELECT 1 FROM HistoryTable h3
                                    WHERE h3.RecordID = h2.RecordID
                                      AND h3.Timestamp < h2.Timestamp 
                                      AND h3.Connected = 1
                              )) + 1 END
FROM HistoryTable h1
ORDER BY RecordID,Timestamp
```

The first `NOT EXISTS` handles the case that there are *no successful calls* at all, the second  `NOT EXISTS` sub-query ensures that there is *no successful-call* record before the counted *non-successful calls*. The `+ 1` at the end adds the successful call to the non-succesful to get the correct number.

Here's a <kbd>**Demo**</kbd>: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7796/5/0

Comment: Perfect, this both solves the problem and teaches me something new :) Thanks!